# How to crawl Microdata values in Simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How to fetch Microdata values in simple html dom.
Example:

```
<div itemprop='Block' aria-label='Not the true Block'>
This is a paragraph.
</div>
```

I would like to fetch 'Not the true Block'.

Comment: [How to access the HTML element's attributes?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access)

Comment: Can you please write a code according to above example

Comment: Hmmm... `var_dump($variable_where_you_have_the_node->{'aria-label'});`? Have you already written part of the script? The question suggests you were stuck in that specific issue...

Comment: Worked for me :)